# How to find where C++ isfinite() is resolved from in shared libraries?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, symbols, nm

I'm trying to track down where `isfinite()` is defined for a C++ application.  I've been running `nm` on the shared libraries to `grep` for `isfinite`, recursively on shared libraries of shared libraries too, but thus far have not found a library that provides a definition for `isfinite`, yet my application resolves the symbol and runs.  Is there a linux tool that will compute the library that resolves a symbol for a particular executable?

Comment: It's a math library function. Will be found when compiled with -lm (by default). Symbols are stripped from libm.a.

Comment: Try turning on the Map file option on your compiler/linker. That will generally list such details about every symbol in the program.
For Gcc it would be something like: -Xlinker -Map=mymapfile.txt

Comment: @user2784234 I think strip means to remove debuginfo but not the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find that symbol in any module, it's most likely that isfinite is a macro instead of function. 
I think it's legal for a library function to be implemented as macro.
you may disassemble your code that calling this function and find it out.